# Insert many rows based on JOIN with static list

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query that accomplishes the task "grant this list of people the same roles as a particular person".

Given the input table `user_roles`

```
user_id | role_id
-----------------
 1      | 22
 2      | 23
 1      | 27
```

and a list of new user id's (3,4,7) that should have the same roles as user 1, I would like to create an INSERT statement based on a `SELECT` that is then outer-joined with the static list to create a cross product with all the combinations. The desired result would be:

```
user_id | role_id
-----------------
 1      | 22
 2      | 23
 1      | 27
 3      | 22
 3      | 27
 4      | 22
 4      | 27
 7      | 22
 7      | 27
```

The inserting part should be no trouble if I can get a SELECT statement to build the data. I've tried various permutations of

```
SELECT role_id, user_id FROM `user_roles` OUTER JOIN ??? WHERE `user_roles`.`user_id` = 1
```

where ??? is a result of some MySQL magic that creates a table like

```
user_id
-------
 3
 4
 7
```

I spent some time trying to come up with SELECT syntax to achieve that, then scrounging advice from here and there I tried to come up with creating a temporary table that I can join to and then delete. (Efficiency is NOT a requirement.) However, I have not found the magic syntax to create a temp table from static data.

If there is some other, more efficient magic looping syntax I'd love to learn about that as well.

In the time it took me to write this question I could have used a text editor to create the query, but where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT role_id,t.user_id FROM user_roles AS r,(SELECT 3 AS user_id UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS user_id UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS user_id) AS t WHERE r.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Not as elegant as I was hoping for, but certainly more elegant than brute-forcing the query with copy-paste.